# Saving XMPP Multi User chat messages through XMPP MessageArchiving in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, xmpp, xmppframework

I am developing a chat application in iOS using XMPP. I have so far successfully implemented and tested a single user chat scenario, i.e. sending, receiving, saving and retrieving messages.

The problem now em facing is that now when handling Multi User Chat scenarios em receiving it but not able to save them using XMPP MessageArchiving hence cant retrieve them either.

Anyone who has gone through this process/problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hey Ahmed - did you ever get any further with this since August?

Comment: Yes I've successfully implemented multiuser chat scenario..

Comment: I had to customize my message packet.. add Addresses tag in it, removed my id from the 'from' tag and replaced it with 'multicast.severname'.. and few more tweaks.

Comment: @AhmedZ. I have successfully tested one to one chat sending and receiving message but not save and retrive those message using XMPP MessageArchiving it got crash due to unavailability of persistancecordinator

Comment: @RohitPathak you are asking about single one to one chat?

Comment: @AhmedZ. Yes i am talking about one to one chat

Comment: how have you initialized the XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage?

Answer (score 2):

Messages with `groupchat` type may be saved within `XMPPRoom.xcdatamodel`, you need to initialize the `XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage` in your xmpp setup like:

`XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *xmppRoomStorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];`

So, this class implements a method to insert all the messages ROOM within the correct data model (in our case,  all the outgoing and incoming messages are saved in XMPPRoom.xcdatamodel).

`- (void)insertMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
             outgoing:(BOOL)isOutgoing
              forRoom:(XMPPRoom *)room
               stream:(XMPPStream *)xmppStream`

More XEP-0045 info http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for a saving room messages

```
NSString *xmppRoomJIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.your_host", @"your_room_name"];

XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:xmppRoomJIDString];

XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *roomCoreDataStorage = [XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];

XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
            initWithRoomStorage:roomCoreDataStorage
            jid:roomJID
            dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"your_nicke_name" history:nil];
[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
```